# Python Static class variables

Tags: python, class, enums

If all I need is to use it as constant enum, is it still better to use "object" ?

```
class COLOR:
    RED = 1
    BLUE = 2
    GREEN = 3
```

vs

```
class COLOR(object):
    RED = 1
    BLUE = 2
    GREEN = 3
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? In Python 3, the two versions of your code do exactly the same thing. Similarly, an `Enum` type (which would be a more appropriate base) was added in Python 3.4.

Comment: I am using python 2.7.8. The planned use will be using COLOR.RED as a a constant. I don't plan to create any color object.

Comment: You are good without inheriting from object

Comment: I know both will work since I have tested it. I was asked by a colleague to include the "object". I want to know if using "object" is indeed better, and why it is better. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you use Python 3.4's `enum.Enum` as your base class. It's been [backported](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34/1.0.3) to Python 2.4+.

Answer (score 0):

In Python3, there is no difference (all classes are "new style")

In Python2 newstyle classes are usually considered to be faster. I'm not sure if there's a difference for such a trivial class though

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is better to use `object` as the base.  There are a few subtle differences, and when you come back in six months, add some new functionality, and don't then subclass from `object`, you'll likely waste valuable time trying to figure out why something isn't working.